# how to set Steps To Reproduce field required in MANTIS

Tags: mantis

Is this possible to setup Steps To Reproduce field so it's required?

It's always difficult to get enough info from reporters, so maybe forcing them to fill this field will help us - programmers - a little.

I would like to still be able to update mantis without troubles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are able to achieve this by changing, (in bug_report.php)

```
$t_bug_data->steps_to_reproduce = gpc_get_string( 'steps_to_reproduce', '' );
```

To

```
$t_bug_data->steps_to_reproduce = gpc_get_string( 'steps_to_reproduce' );
```

But on the advanced report it doesn't show an * (Asterisk) to indicate that it is mandatory. You have to add the * yourself in the PHP file.

Comment: You will probably need to re-apply the change, but I do not see another solution. Maybe you can script the change so you can easily store and re-apply your changes.

Comment: remove the second argument (,'') from that string. That is the change. Does it help?

Comment: Just to complete this, to add the "required" asterisk into the web page via the PHP, add: ```html <span class="required">*</span>``` into the file `bug_report_page.php` so that the line reads: ```html <span class="required">*</span><?php print_documentation_link( 'steps_to_reproduce' ) ?>``` In MantisBT version 1.2.19, this is on line 513.